# Scrapy: How to implement of yield in 3rd party function?

Tags: yield, scrapy

The code looks like following:

```
def parse(self, response):
    param = {}
    self.send_request(self, param)

def send_request(self, param):
    url = "www.sample.com/auto/"
    yield FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse_auto, formdata=param, method="POST")

def parse_auto(self, response):
    ...
```

Why yield does not work in this code? I would like to reuse the send_request in other sections.

Log:

```js
2017-02-26 23:43:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-02-26 23:43:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-02-26 23:43:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-02-26 23:43:16 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-02-26 23:43:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-02-26 23:43:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-02-26 23:43:16 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-02-26 23:43:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.compreseguros.com/> (referer: None)
2017-02-26 23:43:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-02-26 23:43:18 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 291,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 7561,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 26, 15, 43, 18, 32000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 26, 15, 43, 16, 355000)}
2017-02-26 23:43:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

This is log result.
Look at the sent_request function body. There is a change.

Comment: what your `start_urls` look like? Scrapy needs a starting point, either specify a URL in `start_urls` variable or create `def start_requests` method

Comment: Of course there is start_urls variable in the class definition section. The parse function works.

Comment: post your scrapy logs

Comment: I am still looking for any answer.

Comment: Please see my new answer, its fully tested and working on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fully working code.

All you needed is to `return` than method from `parse`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy, logging
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

    class Test1SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "test1_spider"

        start_urls  = ["http://stackoverflow.com"]

        def parse(self, response):
            param = {}
            return self.send_request(param)

        def send_request(self, param):
            logging.info("send_request is called")
            url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
            yield FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse_auto, formdata=param, method="POST")

        def parse_auto(self, response):
            logging.info("parse_auto is called")
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug your spider on your own. Log some helpful messages using logging class.

```
import logging
def parse(self, response):
    logging.info("I am called from parse method")
    param = {}

    url = "www.sample.com/auto/"
    yield FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse_auto, formdata=param, method="POST")

def parse_auto(self, response):
    logging.info("I am called from parse_auto method")
```

Do this and update your question with scrapy logs again. I am sure your code is not going in `send_request` method.

You have `url = "www.sample.com/auto/"` in you code. So make sure you have `www.sample.com/auto/` in your `allowed_domains` variable.

Comment: You are right, self.send_request(...) function does not work. What I want to know is why. and to make it works how?

Comment: @bbanzzakji See my edited, I removed `send_request` ... that seems unnecessary in your code.

Comment: I know that is general workflow of scrapy. I just want to reuse send_request in the more below section. For example my spider has many request-response trees and some requests are very often used in various place. Of course I can put FormRequest in everywhere it is needed. I just want clean and smart code. My way is not possible?

Comment: You have `url = "www.sample.com/auto/"` in you code. So make sure you have `www.sample.com/auto/` in your `allowed_domains` variable.

Comment: Make sure you to check `allowed_domains` variable, or just remove `allowed_domains` for now just for testing.

Comment: Can you change name of `send_request` function to something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136691/discussion-between-umair-and-bbanzzakji).